# How to compose two SQLITE queries with different conditions to return a pair of rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, where-in

I have some delivery data, let's say for UK supermarkets.  The data I am interested in is composed in two `select` queries as follows:

```
select t2.COMNAME, t0.DELDATE, t1.DELSERN, t1.DELEACTVOL, t3.PRODNAME, t3.PRODEANC from TDELIVER t0 inner join TDELENTR t1 on (t1.DELSERN=t0.DELSERN) 
inner join TCOMPANY t2 on (t2.COMSERNO=t0.COMSERNO)
inner join TPRODUCT t3 on (t1.PRODSERN=t3.PRODSERN) 
where t1.DELEACTVOL < 0
```

Which yields results where `DELEACTVOL` is **negative**, something like this, but with many more entries and real data:

[image: Negative Volumes]

```
select t2.COMNAME, t0.DELDATE, t1.DELSERN, t1.DELEACTVOL, t3.PRODNAME, t3.PRODEANC from TDELIVER t0 inner join TDELENTR t1 on (t1.DELSERN=t0.DELSERN) 
inner join TCOMPANY t2 on (t2.COMSERNO=t0.COMSERNO)
inner join TPRODUCT t3 on (t1.PRODSERN=t3.PRODSERN)
```

Which yields **all** results where `DELEACTVOL` is **negative or positive**, something like this:

[image: All Volumes]

As you can see, the two queries are identical aside from the fact one filters out (the majority) of **positive volume** entries.  Each delivery has a unique `DELSERN`.

I need a query that will give me each `DELSERN` (every delivery), such as the `DELSERN` `XXXX.......89`, delivered to Tesco on May 24th, which features some product, say `Product A`, with a `negative delivery volume` **ONLY** if there is in the same delivery a `positive delivery volume` for that product.  In the sample data `XXXX.......37` should not be returned.

I have a feeling I should be using `WHERE IN` or `JOIN` but I don't know.

I have tried:

```
select t2.COMNAME, t0.DELDATE, t1.DELEACTVOL, t3.PRODNAME, t3.PRODEANC from TDELIVER t0 inner join TDELENTR t1 on (t1.DELSERN=t0.DELSERN) 
inner join TCOMPANY t2 on (t2.COMSERNO=t0.COMSERNO)
inner join TPRODUCT t3 on (t1.PRODSERN=t3.PRODSERN) 
where t1.DELEACTVOL < 0
and EXISTS(select p2.COMNAME, p0.DELDATE, p1.DELEACTVOL, p3.PRODNAME, p3.PRODEANC from TDELIVER p0 inner join TDELENTR p1 on (p1.DELSERN=p0.DELSERN) 
inner join TCOMPANY p2 on (p2.COMSERNO=p0.COMSERNO)
inner join TPRODUCT p3 on (p1.PRODSERN=p3.PRODSERN) 
where p1.DELEACTVOL > 0 and t1.DELSERN = p1.DELSERN) 
ORDER by t1.DELEACTVOL
```

... hoping that `and t1.DELSERN = p1.DELSERN` part would do the trick but this returns the same as the the first query.  I guess because EACH delivery which a negative volume for Product A would have at least SOME positive products?  I probably need to take into account `PRODNAME` too?

Any help would be great.

Comment: can there be more than one such pair for a given delesern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `join` the queries on all columns except `deleactvol` and select the required columns.

```
select p1.delsern,p1.deleactvol,p2.deleactvol
from (
select t2.COMNAME, t0.DELDATE,t1.DELSERN, t1.DELEACTVOL, t3.PRODNAME, t3.PRODEANC 
from TDELIVER t0 
inner join TDELENTR t1 on (t1.DELSERN=t0.DELSERN) 
inner join TCOMPANY t2 on (t2.COMSERNO=t0.COMSERNO)
inner join TPRODUCT t3 on (t1.PRODSERN=t3.PRODSERN) 
where t1.DELEACTVOL < 0) p1
join (select t2.COMNAME, t0.DELDATE,t1.DELSERN, t1.DELEACTVOL, t3.PRODNAME, t3.PRODEANC 
      from TDELIVER t0 
      inner join TDELENTR t1 on (t1.DELSERN=t0.DELSERN) 
      inner join TCOMPANY t2 on (t2.COMSERNO=t0.COMSERNO)
      inner join TPRODUCT t3 on (t1.PRODSERN=t3.PRODSERN) 
      where t1.DELEACTVOL > 0) p2
on p1.DELSERN = p2.DELSERN and p1.COMNAME = p2.COMNAME 
and p1.DELDATE = p2.DELDATE and p1.PRODNAME = p2.PRODNAME and p1.PRODEANC = p2.PRODEANC
```

If there can only be one positive and negative deleactvol per delsern, you can do

```
select t2.COMNAME, t0.DELDATE, t1.DELSERN, t3.PRODNAME, t3.PRODEANC 
from TDELIVER t0 
inner join TDELENTR t1 on (t1.DELSERN=t0.DELSERN) 
inner join TCOMPANY t2 on (t2.COMSERNO=t0.COMSERNO)
inner join TPRODUCT t3 on (t1.PRODSERN=t3.PRODSERN) 
group by t2.COMNAME, t0.DELDATE, t1.DELSERN, t3.PRODNAME, t3.PRODEANC
having sum(case when t1.DELEACTVOL < 0 then -1 when t1.DELEACTVOL > 0 then 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks!  Works perfectly